# Call function by name given as a string

Tags: c++, function

Is there possibility in c++ to call function which name was given as a string arg in another function. for example:

```
void func1()
{
// do something
}

void func2()
{
// do something
}

int main()
{
    call("func1");
    call("func2");
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can create a [*`std::map`*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) of [`std::function`<sub>*C++11*</sub>](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)

```
  std::map<std::string, std::function<void()> > call;

  call["func1"] = func1 ;
  call["func2"] = func2 ;
```

Then,

```
  call["func1"]( ) ;
```

Comment: `std::function` seems overkill for this one. Why not simple function pointers ?

Comment: @Quentin IMHO its cleaner and simpler

Comment: Not mine, but probably the reason I cited :/

Answer (score 4):

This is called reflection. Are you using c++11? If so look into the functor. One way to do what you want is to make a map of function pointers with names as string keys.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int Func1() {}
int Func2() {}

typedef void (*FunctionPtr)(void);

int main() {

    std::map<std::string, void (*FunctionPtr)(void)> map;
    map["Func1"] = Func1;
    map["Func2"] = Func2;

    myMap["Func1"]();
}
```